# office-js - check if formula is supported by Excel version

Tags: excel, office-js

Is there a way in office-js to find out if a specific formula is supported by the users current Excel version?

In my case I have a URL to an image. If `=IMAGE` formula is available in the users Excel version I would like to use the formula to insert the image, otherwise I would just insert the URL as hyperlink.